# When we run pytests on a Lambda, it executes properly the first time, but fails second time onwards

Tags: python, lambda, aws-lambda, pytest, serverless

I am trying to run my pytest framework on a lambda so that the tests can be run on a single API call.

I save the reports in the directory "/tmp/report.html" as Lambda only allows to write files in the /tmp directory

After deploying anything new, the test run gets successful. But the moment I trigger the same test again with a API call I get the below error:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "'total_fail'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/handler.py\", line 11, in lambda_handler\n    test_run = pytest.main([\"--html-report=/tmp/report.html\"])\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/_pytest/config/__init__.py\", line 167, in main\n    ret: Union[ExitCode, int] = config.hook.pytest_cmdline_main(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pluggy/_hooks.py\", line 265, in __call__\n    return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pluggy/_manager.py\", line 80, in _hookexec\n    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pluggy/_callers.py\", line 60, in _multicall\n    return outcome.get_result()\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pluggy/_result.py\", line 60, in get_result\n    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pluggy/_callers.py\", line 39, in _multicall\n    res = hook_impl.function(*args)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/_pytest/main.py\", line 317, in pytest_cmdline_main\n    return wrap_session(config, _main)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/_pytest/main.py\", line 305, in wrap_session\n    config.hook.pytest_sessionfinish(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pluggy/_hooks.py\", line 265, in __call__\n    return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pluggy/_manager.py\", line 80, in _hookexec\n    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pluggy/_callers.py\", line 55, in _multicall\n    gen.send(outcome)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/_pytest/terminal.py\", line 818, in pytest_sessionfinish\n    self.config.hook.pytest_terminal_summary(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pluggy/_hooks.py\", line 265, in __call__\n    return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pluggy/_manager.py\", line 80, in _hookexec\n    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pluggy/_callers.py\", line 55, in _multicall\n    gen.send(outcome)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pytest_html_reporter/plugin.py\", line 286, in pytest_terminal_summary\n    self.update_archives_template(base)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pytest_html_reporter/plugin.py\", line 794, in update_archives_template\n    self.load_archive(cf, value='current')\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pytest_html_reporter/plugin.py\", line 815, in load_archive\n    suite_highlights(data)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/pytest_html_reporter/plugin.py\", line 121, in suite_highlights\n    if data['content']['suites'][i]['status']['total_fail'] == 0:\n"
  ]
}
```

Here is my lamda handler python file content:

```
import json
import pytest


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(f'{event}')
    event_raw_path = event['rawPath']

    if event_raw_path == '/run/test':
        test_run = pytest.main(["--html-report=/tmp/report.html"])
        if test_run == pytest.ExitCode.OK:
            result = "PASS"
        else:
            result = "FAIL"
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps('Test Complete, Result - ' + result),
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }

    else:
        return {
            'statusCode': 400,
            'body': json.dumps('Wrong Url Entered'),
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }
```

Cloudwatch logs:

```
[ERROR] KeyError: 'total_fail'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 22, in lambda_handler
    test_run = pytest.main(["--html-report=/tmp/report.html"])
  File "/opt/python/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 167, in main
    ret: Union[ExitCode, int] = config.hook.pytest_cmdline_main(
  File "/opt/python/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
  File "/opt/python/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
  File "/opt/python/pluggy/_callers.py", line 60, in _multicall
    return outcome.get_result()
  File "/opt/python/pluggy/_result.py", line 60, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "/opt/python/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/opt/python/_pytest/main.py", line 317, in pytest_cmdline_main
    return wrap_session(config, _main)
  File "/opt/python/_pytest/main.py", line 305, in wrap_session
    config.hook.pytest_sessionfinish(
  File "/opt/python/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
  File "/opt/python/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
  File "/opt/python/pluggy/_callers.py", line 55, in _multicall
    gen.send(outcome)
  File "/opt/python/_pytest/terminal.py", line 818, in pytest_sessionfinish
    self.config.hook.pytest_terminal_summary(
  File "/opt/python/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
  File "/opt/python/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
  File "/opt/python/pluggy/_callers.py", line 55, in _multicall
    gen.send(outcome)
  File "/opt/python/pytest_html_reporter/plugin.py", line 286, in pytest_terminal_summary
    self.update_archives_template(base)
  File "/opt/python/pytest_html_reporter/plugin.py", line 800, in update_archives_template
    self.load_archive(cf, value='current')
  File "/opt/python/pytest_html_reporter/plugin.py", line 815, in load_archive
    suite_highlights(data)
  File "/opt/python/pytest_html_reporter/plugin.py", line 121, in suite_highlights
    if data['content']['suites'][i]['status']['total_fail'] == 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

> Each AWS Lambda execution environment provides 512 MB of disk space in the `/tmp` directory which can be used for some data processing and can be used for temporary storage. This `/tmp` disk space is preserved for the lifetime of the execution environment and provides a transient cache for data between invocations.

The reason why you don't get the issue after each deploy, is that the `/tmp` directory is flushed after a new deployment. Somehow your tests rely on the `/tmp` to be empty, or maybe `pytest.main` fails because the `/tmp/report.html` file already exists.

Comment: Even I had thought of the same and had added this in order to empty the /tmp drirectory:
`call('rm -rf /tmp/..?* /tmp/.[!.]* /tmp/*', shell=True)`

But that did not help

Comment: Did you check lambda logs in CloudWatch? Do they show why the tests are failing?

Comment: Yes, Its giving the same error as mentioned in the description above. I have added the cloudwatch logs in the description again for your reference. Please help.

Comment: Seems like you're using `pytest-html-reporter` library: https://github.com/prashanth-sams/pytest-html-reporter

Comment: This line is causing the issue: https://github.com/prashanth-sams/pytest-html-reporter/blob/ad20ba9752ae4f94966ae45cb49f035b30ffd525/pytest_html_reporter/util.py#L13

Comment: try deleting these two files at the startup as well: `base + '/output.json'` and `base + '/archive/*.json'`

Comment: I tried to remove all the files from "/tmp" directory as lambda allows only to write files in this directory, but that did not help

Comment: No, not the `/tmp` directory. Please remove files that are besides your python files, since the Lambda function might keep them. just in case.